# What can be preventing this cdn file from loading on my webpage?

Tags: http

I wish I had a more generic way of asking this question but I really can't figure out what could be going on.

Using dev-channel Chrome 26 (and IE 10) I'm hitting a simple html site [in my public dropbox here](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/108084/gigs/allinone/index.html)

In my browser Handlebars.js (from cdnjs.com) never loads and I get an error. Heck, according to the Network tab it never even **tries** to load it. Yet click through the source and the script file - it is definitely a live link.  Why handlebars? Additionally, running the same exact site with a local server loads just fine.

I'm at a loss here what could *possibly* have this effect. You'd think the issue would be running the server in dropbox but it seems to be the actual browser misbehaving. And why on earth does it not make any request at all?

My repo by the way is on [github on the preformance-tuning branch](https://github.com/codemkrs-team-name/codemkrs-challenge)

Comment: Chrome gives an error saying [blocked] The page at as you are trying to access a http content from https site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Chrome is throwing an insecure content warning on your scripts. Most likely because you are trying to access content hosted over HTTP while your site is being served from dropbox using ssl. Most likely a Chrome security setting silently block scripts it considers "insecure"